# remove null keys by regex

Tags: java, json, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to remove null values for some key, I tried with this REGEX but it's not working. please your advice...

```
private static final String REMOVE_NULL_VALS_REGEX = ",\"([^\"]+)\":null|\"([^\"]+)\":null,|\"([^\"]+)\":null";

{
  "event": "111e0d4a",
  "type": "business",
  "eventProducerId": "Billing",
  "eventVersion": "1.0",
  "headerReference": {
    "activityId": "999",
  },
  "payload": {
    "trans": "Line",
    "details": {
      "plan": {
        "features": [
          {
            "featureName": "GSM",
          }
        ],
        "planName": "null"
      },
      "number": {
        "mobileNumber": "111111111"
      },
      "lineType": "GSM"
    },
    "dea": "0000002",
    "sourceBan": "null",
    "financialAccount": {
      "financialAccountNumber": "212121"
    },
    "reasonCode": "null"
  }
}
```

I did the convert to string and I'm trying to remove those null values with regex.

Comment: and you called some kind of regex replace or replaceAll?

Comment: why not parsing to POJO ignoring null values?

Comment: yes, im using with replace all.

Comment: there is no occurrence of `:null` in posted text, so that expression will never match (and regex is not the most appropriate for the job)

Comment: i tried also that one -    private static final String REMOVE_NULL_VALS_REGEX = ",\"([^[ ]*\"]+)\": \"null\"|\"([^[ ]*\"]+)\": \"null\",|\"([^[ ]*\"]+)\": \"null\"";

Comment: this is my string and i want to remove from that string all the key and vals that are nulls -this is the str payload: {"transactionType":"UCCLineAct","dealerCode":"0000002","financialAccount":{"financialAccountNumber":"110885364"},"lineOfServiceDetails":{"lineType":"GSM","number":{"mobileNumber":"4079232335"},"ratePlan":{"planName":"null","features":[{"featureId":"UCCGSM","featureName":"UCC GSM"}]}},"reasonCode":"null","sourceBan":"null"}

Comment: In the example in the question the comma after "999" and the one after "featureName": "GSM" may mess up some json parsers if you try to do those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you use GSON, is very easy library

You can create a pojo with this page: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

And you can create a pojo (java class)

if some value is null then the value of the class be null to.

if you want see a tutorial you can see the following link: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 0):

So as Carlos Heuberger pointed out, you were looking for a colon inside the quotes and that was not matching anything. Here (between the quotation marks) is a regex suitable for replaceAll with "" in your context.

```
"\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"null\""
```

The logic is like this. You look for a quote followed by some stuff besides a quote, then another quote, some stuff besides (the colon  and space typically) then "null". You replace with the empty string. The only downside, is you may leave some commas that are not needed. Assuming none of your strings have commas inside, cleaning them up is achieved by a few more lines of code (as it happens, for the example in the question it also cleans up a couple of other fishy jsons).

So the following would achieve your goal with RegEx (and the other comments and answers here may be right that it's not the best way to go -- I'm just going with your idea).

```
// examples from question or later comment, your choice 
//public static String jStr = "{\r\n  \"event\": \"111e0d4a\",\r\n  \"type\": \"business\",\r\n  \"eventProducerId\": \"Billing\",\r\n  \"eventVersion\": \"1.0\",\r\n  \"headerReference\": {\r\n    \"activityId\": \"999\",\r\n  },\r\n  \"payload\": {\r\n    \"trans\": \"Line\",\r\n    \"details\": {\r\n      \"plan\": {\r\n        \"features\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"featureName\": \"GSM\",\r\n          }\r\n        ],\r\n        \"planName\": \"null\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"number\": {\r\n        \"mobileNumber\": \"111111111\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"lineType\": \"GSM\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"dea\": \"0000002\",\r\n    \"sourceBan\": \"null\",\r\n    \"financialAccount\": {\r\n      \"financialAccountNumber\": \"212121\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"reasonCode\": \"null\"\r\n  }\r\n}";
public static String jStr = "{\"transactionType\":\"UCCLineAct\",\"dealerCode\":\"0000002\",\"financialAccount\":{\"financialAccountNumber\":\"110885364\"},\"lineOfServiceDetails\":{\"lineType\":\"GSM\",\"number\":{\"mobileNumber\":\"4079232335\"},\"ratePlan\":{\"planName\":\"null\",\"features\":[{\"featureId\":\"UCCGSM\",\"featureName\":\"UCC GSM\"}]}},\"reasonCode\":\"null\",\"sourceBan\":\"null\"} ";
public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println(jStr);  // show before we mess with it
  jStr=jStr.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"null\"",""); //replace "blah" :"null"
  jStr=jStr.replaceAll("(,[ \t\r\n\f]*,)+",","); //cut repeated commas separated by at most whitespace, to a single comma
  jStr=jStr.replaceAll("\\{[ \t\r\n\f]*,","\\{"); // remove comma appearing immediately (possibly with whitespace between) after {
  jStr=jStr.replaceAll("\\[[ \t\r\n\f]*,","\\["); // remove comma appearing immediately after [
  jStr=jStr.replaceAll(",[ \t\r\n\f]*\\}","\\}"); // remove comma immediately before }
  jStr=jStr.replaceAll(",[ \t\r\n\f]*\\]","\\]"); // remove comma immediately before ]
  System.out.println(jStr); // show after
}
```

There may be some slicker way to include the possible commas within the regex, but it was getting too hard for me to cover all the cases. Also, in theory [ \t\r\n\f] should be replaceable with [\s], but jdoodle balked at that.